# Issue with 2D array and Java Enums

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, enums, enumeration

I'm new to enums with member fields and constructors, and I can't figure out why I'm getting this syntax error (commented to the spot)(Eclipse). When I change the data type in question to anything other than a 2D array, the error disappears.

```java
public enum KeyboardType {
    ALPHABETICAL_CHARACTERS(
        {
            {'q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'p'},
            {'a', 's', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', ' '},
            {'z', 'x', 'c', 'v', 'b', 'n', 'm', ' ', ' ', ' '}
        }
    ); //Syntax error, insert "Identifier" to complete EnumConstant

    private final char[][] layout;

    KeyboardType(char[][] layout) {
        this.layout = layout;
    }

    public char[][] getLayout() {
        return layout;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is a bit off. You can only use that syntax for initializing an array at array declaration time. Here you aren't declaring a new array variable, so you can't omit the array type. You need something like,

```
ALPHABETICAL_CHARACTERS(new char[][] { 
        { 'q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'p' },
        { 'a', 's', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', ' ' },
        { 'z', 'x', 'c', 'v', 'b', 'n', 'm', ' ', ' ', ' ' } });
```

Comment: That solved it. I don't know why I thought I could pass a 2D array as a literal when they aren't even primitive types, or really data types at all. Thanks!